# Get the value from listbox of template plugin in tinymce

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, tinymce, tinymce-4

I want to add plugin to delete template in tinymce editor. For this I am using same form like template.

For deleting selected template I want the selected value from listbox which contains list of inserted templates. I have used various ways to get it but no luck.

1. `var selectedValue = win.find('#listbox')[0].value();`
2. `getContent()` is also not working.

I am getting `null` value or `undefined` value.

Any ideas for better solutions.